# Busqueda por like db en mysql

Tags: php

mi pregunta es la siguiente
tengo un problema
lo que pasa que intento pasar dos formas de obtener valores mediante like
tanto por descripcion como por codbar.
el codigo es el siguiente

este es el codigo que me busca por descripcion

```
 $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->limit(10);
        $this->db->like('descripcion', $q);
        $query = $this->db->get('produtos');
```

este es el codigo que me busca por codbar

```
 $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->limit(10);
        $this->db->like('codbar', $q);
        $query = $this->db->get('produtos');
```

asi intento poner los dos pero no me busca por los dos, solo por codbar

```
 $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->limit(10);
        $this->db->like('descripcion | codbar', $q);
        $query = $this->db->get('produtos');
```

agradezco mucho su ayuda, gracias.

Comment: si estas usando alg+ún framework sería importante lo menciones

Comment: Eso es codeigniter cierto ?

Comment: No especificas el framework, ni especificas si quieres por `descripción` **Y** por `codbar` o si quieres por `descripción` **O** por `codbar` .

Comment: Hola amigo no estoy usando ningun sigo entre los valores de busqueda.

Comment: hola amigo, por ambos metodos tanto por descripcion y codbar que busque por cualquiera de los dos.

Comment: Le puedes pasar un array asociativo, por ejemplo: `$array = array('descripcion' => $q, 'codbar' => $q);` y luego: `$this->db->like($array);` Está claramente explicado en [la doc de **Codeigniterrrr**](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#looking-for-similar-data). :)  O, aparte si quieres, así: `$this->db->like('descripcion', $q);
$this->db->like('codbar', $q);`

Comment: @A.Cedano me parece que también se pudiera auxiliar de los métodos `like()` y `or_like()`

Comment: @shadow sí, pero no queda muy claro si quiere un `OR` un `AND`... En programación esto `|`  es `OR`.

Comment: $this->db->like('descripcion', $q); $this->db->like('codbar', $q); ya le intente asi pero no me dio resultado.

Comment: Si es por uno **O** por otro, sería así: **`$this->db->like('descripcion', $q); $this->db->or_like('codbar', $q);`**  Si es por uno **Y** por otro sería como se ha indicado en el [comentario anterior](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/212784/busqueda-por-like-db-en-mysql#comment396628_212784).

Comment: Si es por uno O por otro, sería así: $this->db->like('descripcion', $q); $this->db->or_like('codbar', $q);                  perfectisimo amigo solo en la segunda me habia faltado ponerle el or_   porque ponia en el mismo que el primero like en ambos pero no funcionaba, mil gracias.

Comment: entonces @miguel debes tener presente que si estas usando un framework, llamado CodeIgniter aunque al inicio nos dijiste que no, siempre añade toda la info necesaria en tus preguntas

Comment: si amigo, tienes razon, una disculpa, pense que no, pero es un CodeIgniter like, gracias, saludos, buenas noches.

Answer (score 1):

La [documentación](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#looking-for-similar-data) de **[codeigniter](/questions/tagged/codeigniter)** lo explica claramente, necesitas usar

**`or_like()`**

> This method is identical to the one above, except that multiple
>   instances are joined by OR:

combinado con un `like` normal.

Algo así:

```
$this->db->like('descripcion', $q); 
$this->db->or_like('codbar', $q);
```